# Hibernate: One to Many getId() not to fetch compete object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two entity objects, and have one to many association between them.

Lets call them "One" and "Many". I have set the fetching as "Lazy".

So when I have the "Many" object and try to get Id of "One" object Hibernate internally fetched the complete object. Whereas it can give me Id just on the basis of entity "Many" because it would contain the id of "One". **Id of "One" is primary key, and a foreign key in "Many"**

```
many.getOne().getId() //fetches complete "One" object
```

Is it possible and how?

Comment: No it is not possible to get only the id. Hibernate works with objects  not with properties

Comment: Actually I remember a project on which I worked where it was possible. I think that if you don't link both entity with oneToMany annotation but just get the id as if it was a simple Integer, it works. Maybe can you have both attributes in same entity, one and idOne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, of course. You can use `FetchType.LAZY` and get an `id` by this way:

```
LazyInitializer initializer = ((HibernateProxy) many.getOne()).getHibernateLazyInitializer();
Long id = (Long) initializer.getIdentifier();
```

It will work only with foreign key associations, not with join table associations.

Or you can use HQL or criteria with a projection, to get an only `id`.

Comment: Nice, never thought that we could work with lazys like that!

Comment: @VLef Hibernate has a foreign key anyway because it resides in the same table. But It will not work with join tables, of course.

Comment: Sure, but this foreign key is completely hidden by default without loading the entity, that's why it's nice to finally know a way to get it =)

Comment: @VLef You can take a look on my project, if you are interested in not common ways of Hibernate using :)

Answer (score 2):

You should write a HQL query and select only the ids.